What is the wrath of God in John 3:36?
John 3:36 states "The [one] believing in the Son has life eternal ; the[one] however not obeying the Son will not see life, but the wrath of God abides on him" {Bible Hub interlinear at https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/3-36.htm }
The verb μένει "abides" is present tense indicative active if I understand Koine Greek grammar correctly.
Assuming that the wrath of God is presently occurring, exactly what is it? This cannot refer to future judgment or the "final" wrath of God. Does Paul gives us a hint in Romans 1 of what this wrath really is?

As simple as it is, the answer is within John 3:36: the consequence for someone upon whom God's wrath abides is that they will not see life.
The word "life" in John 3:36 refers to "eternal life". The judgement is in the future. As long as God's wrath abides upon someone in the present, this person will not see life in the final judgement.
In the Old Testament, God's wrath is mentioned in Deuteronomy 9:8, 2 Kings 22:13, Isaiah 13:13 and Jeremiah 7:20, all referring to the destruction of the disobedient Israelites. It is essential to discern God's wrath from human's wrath. God's wrath is a manifestation of His righteousness, unlike human's wrath, which mainly stems from hatred or anger.
In Romans 1:18, Paul reaffirms that God's wrath is on godless and wicked people. They have existed in the past, are present now, and will continue into the future. Their consequence is the same: they will not see eternal life.

God's wrath is His fury, or anger.

And in the abundance of Thine excellency Thou throwest down Thy withstanders, Thou sendest forth Thy wrath -- It consumeth them as stubble. (Ex. 15:7, YLT)

The word translated as "wrath" at Ex. 15:7 is Strong's H2740. "charon" and means fury, anger, a burning of anger. (Biblehub)
The word "wrath" at John 3:36 is Strong's 3709 "orge" which means anger or indignation, and can also be used to indicate punishment or vengeance. (Biblehub)
God's anger is upon those who deny the gift of His Son's sacrifice, counting it as something small, unimportant, or insignificant.  So any who do not obey the Son (repent, believe & be baptized - Mark 16:16, Acts 2:38) have God's anger over them, which will result in their eventual judgment if they do not repent of their sin of denial of Jesus' sacrifice.  That is an active and present condition while they continue in their denial of Him. God cannot do anything for those who reject His Son and they will be denied eternal life.
